# the event listener registered in my Link Function is not triggered

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code inside my link function of custom directive definition and I can see a scroll event listener for the element in chrome. But the handler function is not invoked when I scroll the table.

```
element.find('table').scroll(function () {
            console.log("scrolled");
});
```

Please help me to identify the issue. Here is the JsFiddle illustrating the issue
http://jsfiddle.net/4kLdLb4g/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `overflow: auto` on the `tbody` element, so the event must be bound to that element.

```
    element.find('tbody').scroll(function () {
            console.log("scrolled");
     });
```

**JSFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4kLdLb4g/5/**

Comment: Yep sorry for the wrong answer It's early here in France @Moogs

Comment: am i missing something here?

Comment: @DivyaMV Nope. user Renan posted a wrong answer deleted. That is all.